# Social media management tool

Tags: facebook, social-networks, twitter, google+

I am currently looking for a social media management tool where I have at least the following functionalities. I have already looked around for a few days, but there are so many with so many different functionalities and purposes. I am just overwhelmed.

**Social Media**

1. Facebook (Business page)
2. Twitter
3. GooglePlus (Business page)

**Functions**

- Schedule posts for at least one week ahead
- Being able to implement pictures, links, videos etc
- Facebook promotion functions
- Analytics of past posts

If you know a program having these functions, it would be nice if you would let me know. Since I am just starting, I would prefer a free/open-source solution, but I am not against paying a reasonably price.

Comment: 8 years have passed. What is your tool now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Hootsuite](https://hootsuite.com/).
You can input images, links, and texts. Also, you can schedule it as well.
You can use [Likealyzer](https://likealyzer.com/) for analytics.

Comment: This is actually what I am currently using, after having asked this question 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I think [bufferapp.com](http://bufferapp.com) does what you want. I'm unsure about facebook promotions as that's not something I've used. It has the other features you've listed.

They have a free version, premium versions start at $50/month.

Comment: bufferapp is ok, it seems to have all the functions for sheduling Posts and I am able to add more social accounts then at https://hootsuite.com/plans, but I am not able to add FB Business page without getting premium. So I´gues I´ll go with https://hootsuite.com/plans. I also can purchase several hundret apps there for Addition functionality for 5€.